# How to split downloading from central maven repo and execution of Gatling scenario into different tasks in Azure Pipeline

Tags: maven, azure-pipelines, gatling

I have a simple pipeline in Azure, in which Gatling scenario executes: [Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqXnX.jpg).

Before executing the scenario, files are downloaded from the central maven repository: [Downloading-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxkTS.jpg), [Downloading-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwdIN.jpg).
It takes some time. And then the Gatling [Scenario starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdp60.jpg).

How to split downloading from central maven repository and execution of Gatling scenario into different tasks in Azure Pipeline?

I need it, because I have another pipeline, that starts after current and measures the runtime of task (in which Gatling scenario executes) and compare last runtime with previous. And I don't need to take into account the extra time for downloading files from the repository.

Comment: Hi Artsiom, any update on this issue, have you figured out it?

Comment: Hi, PatrickLu. I added another task to the beginning of the pipeline, and added a very simple script to my Gatling project. In the first task, I execute the PowerShell command <mvn gatling:test '-Dclassname=org.example.OtherSimulation'> for a new simple script (in this case all the necessary files are downloaded from central Maven repository). Then in next task I execute PowerShell command <mvn gatling:test '-Dclassname=org.example.SimulationForAzure'> for my main Gatling scenario, and it executes without downloading any files and dependencies (that's what I need).

Answer (score 0):

Downloading from the central maven repository and executing Gatling scenario are both included in one command :

```
mvn gatling:test
```

Azure DevOps pipeline is just a tool to run your tasks, it could not split one command into two tasks.

This case seems more related with Gatling and Maven not Azure DevOps side. If there are some other commands to complete downloading package and executing Gatling separately, you could add two **PowerShell Script tasks** to run those commands.